# Interpolation in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

I have a x-array and a y-array (numpy, python). The y array is some function of x. The x-array is:

```
x = np.array([1,4,5,7,11])
```

The y array is:

```
y = np.array([4,8,9,11,14])
```

I want to obtain the values of y at values of x that I choose (but which are not there in the pre-existing x-array). For example, the new x-array is:

```
x_new = = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

What is the best (and **most accurate**) way to do this **interpolation** problem in python? I am new to python and I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Most accurate interpolation is a tricky problem and has no correct answer. I can give you an interpolation that passes through all the points exactly and is relatively smooth in between them, but blows up completely to either side of the x values.

Comment: And, by the way, there is nothing Python specific about that. You would be better to ask about best interpolation in a math or statistics oriented forum, then ask here about how best to implement it in Python.

Comment: The new x_array is not meet you request, please check it.

Comment: @Omnifarious: thanks for the reply. Any interpolation method is good. I am new to implementation of this in python. I will be hugely thankful if you can show how to do it.

Comment: @saul: I did not understand. Why is the new x_array not meet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the better interpolation method is from [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline)

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
        xi = np.array([1,4,5,7,11])
        yi = np.array([4,8,9,11,14])
        x_new = = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

        s = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(xi, yi)
        y = s(x_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well a good start would be to look at [Numpy's interpolation method.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) Can get the job done for most situations.